# Autoresizing of subviews ( UICollectionView) on orientation change

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, autolayout, autoresize

I have Created a CustomView ganttChartView and added it from storyboard . Now on ganttChartView I have a UICollection View which will represent timeLine and added programatically.

```
// Initialize GanttChat View from Interface Builder or Storyboard File 
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self= [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    self.timeLineHeight =KMinTimeLineCellHeight;
    self.timeLineCellWidth=kMinTimeLineCellWidth;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    }
 return self;
 }

-(void)reloadTimelineView
 {
  [self initializeTimeLineView];

  [self.timeLineCollectionView reloadData];
 }

-(void) initializeTimeLineView
{
// Initialization of StartDate End Date and DateMode Property
[self initializeTimeLineDates];

// Creating Layout for Collection view
UICollectionViewFlowLayout* flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

CGSize  cellSize =CGSizeMake(self.timeLineCellWidth, self.timeLineHeight) ;
flowLayout.itemSize = cellSize ;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing= 1.0f;
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing=5.0f;

CGRect timeLineFrame =CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, self.timeLineHeight);

// Initialization of CollectionView for TimeLine
self.timeLineCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:timeLineFrame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

  [self.timeLineCollectionView registerClass:[A3TimeLineCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:timeLineCell_ID];
self.timeLineCollectionView.backgroundColor = self.timeLineBackgroundColor;

// Initialization of CollectionView DataSource and Delegate with Start Date and End date and DateMode
self.timeLineDataSource = [[A3GanttChartTimeLineDelegate alloc] initWithDate:self.startDate andDate:self.endDate withMode:self.dateType];

self.timeLineDataSource.gantChartView = self;
self.timeLineDataSource.timeLineEachCellColor = self.timeLineEachCellColor;

self.timeLineCollectionView.delegate=self.timeLineDataSource;
self.timeLineCollectionView.dataSource=self.timeLineDataSource;


[self addSubview:self.timeLineCollectionView];

}
```

Now From Storyboard I have disabled AutoLayout option and from  size Inspector of ganttChartView I have set top and left corner fixed so that it resized after orientation change .

[image]

Now the problem is that TimeLineCollection View is not resizing on orientation change to Landscape. As its added programatically So What I need to do make it resized on orientation change .

Profit Mode

[image]

Landscape Mode

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set also right corner fixed in order to resize after orientation change

Answer (score 0):

```
self.timeLineCollectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it didn't worked for me. Is there any way that we use NSLayoutConstraint programatically to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue using NSLayoutConstraint .

```
// NSLayoutConstraint for making same width of timelineCollectionView with the GanttChart

NSLayoutConstraint *timeLineCollectionViewWidth =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:self.timeLineCollectionView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                   relatedBy:0
                                   toItem:self
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:0];

 [self addConstraint:timeLineCollectionViewWidth];

// NSLayoutConstraint for making same left position  of timelineCollectionView with the GanttChart

NSLayoutConstraint *timeLineCollectionViewLeft = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:self.timeLineCollectionView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                 toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 multiplier:1.0f
                                                 constant:0.f];
[self addConstraint:timeLineCollectionViewLeft];

// NSLayoutConstraint for seting height  of timelineCollectionView 

NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.timeLineCollectionView
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier:1.0
                              constant:self.timeLineHeight];
[self.timeLineCollectionView addConstraint:heightConstraint];
```